Interactive chart web scrape
I would like to get access to the CVOL index data and Skew data, but not sure how to write code for this.
example of one of the charts for a commodity
It comes from this site: https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/cme-group-volatility-indexes.html
I have tried to use prior web scraping code to get the data, but I think because it is sitting in a separate window on the page this is not possible? Not sure.
